# Search text on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to search text on javascript.

```
var v=20;
str = "The rain 20 in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
var patt1=/ain  v/gi;
var n = str.match(patt1);
alert(n);
```

i am trying it but not getting any result.
Where am i wrong, any buddy can you please help me out.

Comment: whats `str`?  Its not defined

Comment: What are you trying to search for?

Comment: sorry, i updated my question please see again.

Comment: I want to search ain 20 but ain is constant and 20 come throe var v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var v = 20; // Variable part of search query
var str = "The rain 20 in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; // String to search
var n = str.match('ain ' + v); // The searching, returns null if not found or the matches found. Notice the 'ain' string has been added (this can of course be changed)

if(n != null){ // if not null
   alert(n + ' found!');
}else{ // if null
   alert(v + ' not found...');   
}
```

I think this will help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/xFeAH/

Answer (score 1):

```
var v=20;
var str = "The rain 20 in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain";
var patt1=new RegExp("ain " + v, "gi");
var n = str.match(patt1);
alert(n); // alerts 'ain 20'
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2wbm/)

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing the point because question was very broad, but you could also use `str.indexOf(findThisString)`